# breaking exception '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>'

Tags: flutter, http, dictionary, dart

I ran a flutter upgrade today...

I'm now on v0.2.11 and I'm getting a strange runtime error in this function:

```
Future apiCall([Map params = const {}]) async {
  loading = true;
  Map stringParams = {};
  params.forEach((k,v)=>stringParams[k.toString()] = v.toString());
  Uri url = new Uri.https(apiDomain, apiPath, stringParams);
  print(url);
  var result = await http.post(
    url,
    body: {'apikey': apiKey}
  );
  loading = false;
  print(result.body);
  return json.decode(result.body);
}
```

I'm calling the function without any params and I get the subtype error.

This code works in DartPad.

Does anyone have an idea what might be going on?

Comment: This isn't an answer in and of itself, but [this page](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/sound-problems#invalid-casts) might be of help for you to understand the new type-safe features in Dart 2.0.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The constructor for [`Uri.https`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/Uri/Uri.http.html) requires a Map with a runtime type of `Map<String, String>`.  When you create `stringParams` without any type annotations, you are actually creating a `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`.  The correct way to create this for Dart 2 is

```
Map<String, String> stringParams = {};
// or
var stringParams = <String, String>{};
```

The reason this used to work is that in Dart 1, even in strong mode, `dynamic` was fuzzy and acted like both `Object` and `null` - meaning a dynamic type was assignable to and from anything.  In Dart 2, `dynamic` acts just like `Object`, except you can call methods or access properties on it without a downcast.

Comment: What happens if my object is of type Map<String, dynamic>. How to make a post request in that case? It keeps giving the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 12):

I used this

```
    if(json["key"]!= null){
       this.active_guests = json["key"].cast<String, int>();
     }
```

Comment: How about nested maps :'(

Answer (score 1):

You can send nested JSON params like this:

1. Convert it to a string using `json.encode`.
2. Send "Content-Type:application/json" in header.

```flutter
var uri = "${Config.baseURL}/your/endpoint";
var headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};
final response = await http.post(
  uri,
  body: json.encode(data),
  headers: headers
);
```