# Convert dart http.get request to match the constructor

Tags: dart, flutter

I have the following code in dart:

```
final uri = Uri.https('api.server', '/json/pages', queryParams);
final response =
    await http.get(uri, headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
```

However the app is throwing an exception citing:

```
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, Object>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>'
```

How do I convert the response to a valid type expected by http.get's constructor or is there another workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to fix the queryParams

```
Map<String, String> stringParams = {};
// or
var stringParams = <String, String>{};
```

[Look at here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49824167/breaking-exception-internallinkedhashmapdynamic-dynamic-is-not-a-subtype-o)